# how would i write a kernel module that runs program b whenever program a is called

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm pretty new to linux, and I have a few questions about kernel module programming. I'm using ubuntu and C to make my .ko files. I'm trying to make a module that will execute program /b instead of /a whenever program /a is called. any tips?

also, even with printk (KERN_EMERG...), it won't print to the terminal. is there a setting i'm missing, or does ubuntu not do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to fiddle with the settings in `/proc/sys/kernel/printk`, which controls which levels are printed to the console. From `proc(5)`:

```
   /proc/sys/kernel/printk
          The four values in this file are console_loglevel,
          default_message_loglevel, minimum_console_level, and
          default_console_loglevel.  These values influence
          printk() behavior when printing or logging error
          messages.  See syslog(2) for more info on the
          different loglevels.  Messages with a higher priority
          than console_loglevel will be printed to the console.
          Messages without an explicit priority will be printed
          with priority default_message_level.
          minimum_console_loglevel is the minimum (highest)
          value to which console_loglevel can be set.
          default_console_loglevel is the default value for
          console_loglevel.
```

Note that, like `nice(2)` values, the *lower* values have *higher* priorities.

The easiest way to make an `execve()` for path `/foo/a` to execute `/foo/b` is to bind-mount `/foo/b` on top of `/foo/a`:

```
mount -obind /foo/b /foo/a
```

No kernel module is required.

Doing this same task with a kernel module would be significantly more work; the LSM interface may provide you with some assistance in figuring out when exactly your target is being executed. If you're looking for a starting point, `do_execve()` in `fs/exec.c` is where to start reading. Be sure to have `ctags` installed, run, and know how to use your editor's `ctags` integration, to make reading the code significantly easier.

Answer (score 0):

Answer about `printk`:
It prints to the console, not the terminal. But what's the console?
You can find its TTY in `/proc/cmdline`. Normally it's `tty0`, which means the screen connected to the computer.
If you connect via SSH/TELNET, surely you won't see this.
If you're working in a graphical environment (Gnome/KDE), you may need something like alt-F1/F2 to switch to a text mode TTY.

You can also use the `dmesg` command to see the messages.